# What is divergence of this function?

Tags: vector-analysis

Let

$$\vec{f}(x_1,x_2) = g_1(x_1,x_2) \hat{i} + g_2(x_1,x_2) \hat{j} + g_3(x_1,x_2) \hat{k}$$

then using the definition of divergence we get,

$$\mathrm{div} f = \sum_{i = 1}^{2} \frac{\partial{g_i}}{\partial x_i}$$

what happens to $ \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x_{what}}$, since I don't have third co-ord to take derivative with?

How is divergence defined for such cases if at all?

Comment: What's the derivative of a constant?

Comment: zero. 0. It is.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the divergence does not exist.

Divergence is a characteristic defined for functions of the form $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$. See the [WA](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divergence.html) and [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates) articles.

The function in your example is of the form $\mathbf{G}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. You cannot take $\text{div}\,\mathbf{G}$.

Answer (score 0):

The divergence is given by 
$$\left\langle \nabla , f \right\rangle   = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_i}$$
$$=\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+0$$

As your last term is independent of $x_3$.

Comment: But I don't have any $x_3$!?

Comment: You can *extend* $f$ to be a function of three variables but it is no longer the same $f$ as stated in the problem. The divergence simply does not exist since it doesn't make sense (as OP is indicating with his/her difficulties).

Comment: You can argue that $f$ can be extended by defining some $f'(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2)$, but this answer in no way even indicates that.